# production app urban airship

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com, dev-to-production

I have implemented Urban airship for development successfully . I create a production app and set up the key and secret in airshipConfig file where ad hoc : YES.
I generate SSL certificate for production and uploaded to urban airship.

I want to send test notification to be sure it's work. I get device token in the audience (which is the same as I used in development) but I get error in console 
"Apple Push service rejected device token XXXXXXX ". other error in console is "there is no active device " ... the status show inactive if I close the app or set the app in background.

So, Can I test the production while the app is not uploaded in app store ? what shall I do to test production?

plz , I'm totally confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO you can test the notification service through `Development` mode only.

The `Production` mode can only be tested once after app will be `live`.

If you have tested the app successfully sending the notification in Development mode than you will be able to send notification successfully in Production mode too.

Comment: thank you for ur reply .. I was totally lost ..everything is done the same as development..
I would like to be sure .. in development Can I get more than one device token in my account and push notification to both devices?... I'm trying to test in new device now but only the first one gets the token

Comment: Ya. You can test push notification in more than one devices using `Development`. You just need to install the app in the devices with same `BundleID` and `Profile`.

Comment: Excuse me .. what do you mean exactly by profile ? I want my friend to test with his device .. I give him the same project and instal it well ..but device token is null in log

Comment: do you mean the certificate? Or the .p12 file which is uploaded to my account at urban airship ?

Comment: I know  i am very late to ask.. But i have same question: If i load my app from Xcode to my device means in development mode and send push notification it's working but if i generate build and try to load this build in different device push notification not work. @Twinkle If you got solution for it please share.